# Rails 3.2 build_association is null'ing out my foreign key when the form loads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I think I need a little help understanding how a simple Rails 3.2 one-to-one association with a nested form works. I have a points form and when I visit it for the first time it loads with everything empty. And when I save everything looks good, it even has the right foreign key. Now, when I try to edit this record again by loading the form, the foreign key (results.pickem_id) gets nulled out and nothing loads in the form. It gets nulled the second `@pickem.build_result` is called. What do I need to do to allow editing of this form? I feel like I'm on the right track here so hopefully I'm missing something simple. I've included just the relavant code snippets but can provide more if need be.

Pickem.rb

```
  attr_accessible :result_attributes 
  has_one :result
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :result
```

Result.rb

`belongs_to :pickem`

pickems_controller.rb

```
  def update
    @pickem = Pickem.find params[:id]

    if @pickem.update_attributes params[:pickem]
      redirect_to pickem_path(@pickem), :notice => 'The pickem has been successfully updated.'
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end

  def results #This is the results form
    @pickem = Pickem.find params[:id]
    @pickem.build_result #:pickem_id => params[:id]
  end
```

results.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for @pickem, :html => {:class => "form-horizontal"} do |f| %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :result do |r| %>
    <%= r.input :pickem_id, :input_html => { :value => params[:id] }, :as => 'hidden' %>
    <%= r.input :first_name, :label => 'First Name:' %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I feel it's kinda messy but maybe it will work.

```
@pickem.result = @pickem.build_result if @pickem.result.blank?
```

Comment: You sir, are the man. That worked. Not sure if it's the preferred "Rails way" but it seems pretty simple.